# how to hide the button in react native app

Tags: reactjs, react-native

how to hide the button only in view in my React native app ?
This is my code if i remove the button then dropdown not shown so what can i do to hide the button ?

```
<View style={styles.container}>
      <Picker
           selectedValue={this.state.PickerSelectedVal}
           onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => this.setState({PickerSelectedVal: itemValue})} >

           <Picker.Item label="India" value="India" />
           <Picker.Item label="USA" value="USA" />
           <Picker.Item label="China" value="China" />
           <Picker.Item label="Russia" value="Russia" />
           <Picker.Item label="United Kingdom" value="United Kingdom" />
           <Picker.Item label="France" value="France" />

         </Picker>

         <Button title="Get Selected Picker Value" onPress={ this.getSelectedPickerValue } />
      </View>
```

Comment: Does the answer solve your problem ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At your state object :

```
constructor(){
    super();
    this.state ={
      showButton: false
    }
  }
```

At your render part you can do something like :

```
{this.state.showButton && <Button title="Get Selected Picker Value" onPress={ this.getSelectedPickerValue } />}
```

And, you can use these to show or hide your button:

```
this.setState({showButton: true})
```

Comment: This one is working and now how to show place holder in picker ? i already tried to put a placeholder but it's not working.